# Both journald and rsyslog are running

Tags: 15.04, rsyslog, systemd-journald

Since the migration to Ubuntu 15.04 both `journald` and `rsyslog` are installed and running.
I'm wondering if this is by design or if rsyslog might not have been uninstalled by accident?

Can I uninstall rsyslog without problems or should I take precautions?

Comment: You almost certainly mean `journald` not `journalctl`.

Comment: Correct. I adjusted the text

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**UPDATE AS OF 18.04:**

As of 18.04, there doesn't seem to be any real dependencies. Aside from other rsyslog specific packages, most of the dependencies listed by `apt-cache rdepends rsyslog` appear to be "recommends" and not actual dependencies.

Therefore, it might be safe but proceed with caution.

**To assess the situation, you can do a "dry run" removal to show which packages would be removed:**

```
sudo apt remove --dry-run rsyslog
```

This will not remove any packages but it will show which packages would be removed.

---

**If you remove rsyslog**, `apt` may install another package to replace it. This is the case when there is an "either/or" dependency for rsyslog or a similar package.

Example:

```
Depends: rsyslog | inetutils-syslogd
```

Here, either package will satisfy the dependency so if you uninstall one, the other will install automatically to satisfy the dependency.

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER (15.04):**

`journalctl` is part of `systemd`.

Many packages depend on `rsyslog` and it is not recommended to uninstall it.

see:

```
apt-cache rdepends rsyslog
```

Comment: Does this mean that I shouldn't - on Kubuntu 18.04 - follow the advice at https://askubuntu.com/questions/925440/relationship-of-rsyslog-and-journald-on-ubuntu-16-04 to mask rsyslogd? I have a handful of rdepends on rsyslog.

Comment: @pbhj I cannot say without knowing the specifics. Masking will not "break your dependencies" in `dpkg` or `apt` but may theoretically cause some issues. You can try and see what happens, especially if you use another log service. Alternatively, if you want to play it safe, you can `disable` the service instead of using `mask` so that the service will not automatically start at boot but will start if called upon by another service.  See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/816285/what-is-the-difference-between-systemctl-mask-and-systemctl-disable

Comment: my `apt-cache` show only a handful of commands using `rsyslog`, most of which i never use.

Comment: @blueray Thanks! I updated the answer.