# A start job is running for wait for network to be configured. Ubuntu server 17.10

Tags: networking, 17.10

i just installed ubuntu server on my laptop and everything works fine except for the fact that at boot if the laptop is not connected to ethernet or in range of my wi-fi i get this message "A start job is running for wait for network to be configured" that stays for about 2 minutes. I looked up online for solutions and i tried to:

- Disable network manager
- Edit timeout settings in /etc/systemd/system.conf
- Disable systemd.networkd-wait-online.service

None of these solutions worked for me. Any possible fixes?

Comment: Those are the fixes. After each change, did you reload NM/systemd? They only read their config files at start.

Comment: Yes i used systemctl daemon-reload, still the same result

Comment: Really obscure problem! I fixed it using the @user914826's answer as well, but using the file `/etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml`.

Comment: @aderchox what should I do in the file /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml

Comment: I solved this by NOT having `optional: true` in my 00-installer-config.yaml due to bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/2036358 - but I still have `ignore-carrier: true`.

Comment: Noting for the record that this is still broken as of jammy 22.04.4.  I have builtin ethernet on my motherboard and a Mellanox MCX311A NIC.  Was able to fix this by adding `optional: true` to my `00-installer-config.yaml` under the entry for my motherboard's ethernet device id.

Answer (score 177):

Don't mask or disable the systemd service.

Edit `/etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml` and add `optional: true` to any devices **that may not always be available**.

```
sudo netplan apply
```

NOTE: setting all interfaces as `optional: true` will not work. It will still default to waiting for 120 seconds. Do not mark the ones required for boot (e.g. the one connected to your Wifi or Ethernet network).

Comment: In my case it only worked after setting all interfaces to optional: true

Comment: In what way is this superior to disabling the systemd service?

Comment: For me with Ubuntu 18.04 on Vmware, the corresponding file was /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml; adding optional: true & reboot worked!  Related thread: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1090631/start-job-is-running-for-wait-for-network-to-be-configured-ubuntu-server-18-04.    Related info on netplan: https://www.linux.com/learn/intro-to-linux/2018/9/how-use-netplan-network-configuration-tool-linux (Configuring DHCP)

Comment: Thisx worked for me with Ubuntu 18.04.03 LTS (Desktop) where I have disabled NetworkManager and set up networkd with netplan, ans set up br0 for kdvm/qenu virtualisation and dns caching with dnsmaquerade. Newer did not find what goes wrong with my settings, but booys take over 2 minutes without optional: true -setting. With that setting boot is normal and so is functionality also with network.

Comment: This worked, but I don't understand why. The "*optional: true*" setting indicates that the device is "not required for booting". But what if it is? Isn't this going to create other  issues when another step during the boot process needs an internet connection for example? I only have 1 interface (eth0, connected to the internet) which should always be present. Why would it need 2 minutes to "become available"? What is it waiting for?

Comment: it's not workin for me in ubuntu 20.04 in virtualbox

Comment: @mae I'm just guessing, but perhaps the DHCP client was waiting for a DHCP Offer from the DHCP server, and for some reasons never received one, and reverted to a previously-working setting. In the background, the DHCP client actually will retry after some time (because DHCP Offers do expire)

Comment: 20.04 ubuntu server, I edited the file called /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml

Comment: This does not work for me. I still have to endure 3 min delay each boot. Considering switching to another distro.

Comment: Clarifying - only mark the unused interfaces as `optional: true`. I initially marked them all as optional and only AFTER I removed `optional: true` from my main ethernet/network interface did it skip the Wait for Network 120 second step in the boot.

Answer (score 87):

Use

```
systemctl disable systemd-networkd-wait-online.service
```

to disable the wait-online service to prevent the system from waiting on a network connection, and use

```
systemctl mask systemd-networkd-wait-online.service
```

to prevent the service from starting if requested by another service (the service is symlinked to `/dev/null`).

Comment: What means _masking_ in this context?.

Comment: It worked. :) Can you please describe what we have done here? I am just curious.

Comment: @SD @jaime-hablutzel 
See https://askubuntu.com/a/816378/445084 for an explanation of `systemctl mask`.

Long story short: masking a service redirects it to `/dev/null`, preventing it from being re-enabled in the case that it is required by another service.

Comment: I was following advice elsewhere to just disable the service, but it kept getting re-enabled.  Masking it (and NetworkManager-wait-online.service) seems to have done the trick.

Comment: You saved my life. It worked

Comment: Is this at least not worse than the selected answer which edits some config file?

Comment: This is a solution that works on Ubuntu 22.04.

Answer (score 24):

This means `systemd-networkd-wait-online.service` is hanging. There's a few known bugs with it. Check what services want [`network-online.target`](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/NetworkTarget/) with:

```
systemctl show -p WantedBy network-online.target
```

You can disable those services if you want. Otherwise, you may have to mask the service as Mr.Ecco [indicated](https://askubuntu.com/a/979493/11392).

Answer (score 22):

Masking `systemd-networkd-wait-online.service`, as suggested in other answers, may help in simple setups but it does not fix the problem. If you mask the service then all other services depending on it will also fail. That means, all services needed to wait until the network is online will fail.

I run into this problem because I use a [dynamic fail-over setup](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/78788/79866) for my devices with **bonding** the wired (e.g. enp9s0) and wireless (e.g. wlp12s0) interface that are used as slaves for the main interface **bond0**. Exactly the same situation do you have if you use a bridge (**br0** with slave interfaces). Only the main interfaces **bond0** or **br0** will get online but not the slaves so `systemd-networkd-wait-online.service` will fail on the slaves.

The solution to this problem is to modify the service and ignore the interfaces that are slaves and does not signal to be online. You will find with:

```
~$ sudo systemctl cat systemd-networkd-wait-online.service | grep --after-context=3 '\[Service\]'
[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/lib/systemd/systemd-networkd-wait-online
RemainAfterExit=yes
```

The program **systemd-networkd-wait-online** has a parameter to ignore specific interfaces. Check with `/lib/systemd/systemd-networkd-wait-online --help`. So I make a drop in file to modify the service and ignore the slave interfaces:

```
~$ sudo systemctl edit systemd-networkd-wait-online.service
```

In the empty editor insert these statements, of course with your interface names, save them an quit the editor:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/lib/systemd/systemd-networkd-wait-online --ignore=enp9s0 --ignore=wlp12s0 --quiet
```

The empty `ExecStart=` is important because it disables the "old" command. You can check for more than one interface (look at the help).

Comment: Excellent, very good answer, that was exactly my problem

Comment: isnt this same end result as using `optional: true` in netplan config?

Comment: If the file doesn't exist use **--force**. 
`systemctl edit --force systememd-networkd-wait-online.service`

Comment: @linux64kb The option `--force` is not needed. The drop in file is always created. That's the reason why the editor is empty. The option does not have any impact.

Comment: @linux64kb please fix `systemed`

Comment: I  can say that the command solved my problem, there were no other issues and I never repair a system that just works fine. Thanks for the advice though.

Answer (score 4):

This may not work for everyone, but it worked for me in Ubuntu 18.04 and Ubuntu 20.04.

I use SLAAC for IPv6 IP addresses, but I had `dhcp6: yes` in my `/etc/netplan/01.netplan.yaml` file and experienced the 2-minute delay on boot. I changed it to `dhcp6: no` and the 2-minute wait disappeared, but I still get my SLAAC IP address.

I don't completely understand why. Someone in the future may edit this answer to explain (or confirm?). I believe Netplan is trying to use DHCPv6 to get the IPv6 address and it takes a long time (2 minutes?) to fail before giving up.

Answer (score 4):

This is an oldie that appears to be resurfacing in 20.10.

Along the same lines as [the previous answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1279874/134479), what worked here is adding `link-local: [ ]` to every interface in `/etc/netplan/*.yaml`.  This overrides the default value of `[ ipv6 ]` (see `man 5 netplan`).

Then apply the change (`sudo netplan apply`), and `networkctl -a` should show the state of the interfaces as `configured` rather than `configuring`.  Also, `systemctl start systemd-networkd-wait-online` returns immediately with success.

This is on a system with disabled IPv6 stack (`ipv6.disable_ipv6=1` on the kernel commandline), so the bug appears to be that `systemd-networkd-wait-online` is waiting in vain for a link-local IPv6 interface to be configured.

Comment: fwiw I tried setting `link-local: [ ]` as well as `dhcpv6: false` for all my interfaces, and this did not work for me. I suppose that is not enough if I do not also disable IPv6 elsewhere.

Comment: What would be the setup for ipv4?

Answer (score 3):

I have a machine with 5 Ethernet ports and besides the first one I used the other four sporadically.

Assigned static IPs to the ones I used more often and added "optional: true" on all others. The boot up does not hang and wait only 2~3 seconds for configuring network services.

Answer (score 1):

in my case the offending service were related to ISCSI, and I solved it masking the services as follows:

```
systemctl mask open-iscsi.service iscsid.service iscsid.socket
```

This solution works if you don't need to use the services, otherwise you need a working configuration for your ISCSI