# Can't SSH to Raspberry Pi via wired connection with static IP

Tags: server, 18.04, ssh, network-manager, netplan

My Raspberry Pi 3B+ is running on [Ubuntu Server 18.04](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-server/bionic/daily-preinstalled/current/bionic-preinstalled-server-arm64+raspi3.img.xz).  I have it connected to my PC via ethernet dongle in link-local mode.

I tried adding a static IP on the Pi with netplan, but I couldn't connect at all. I'm getting a "no route to host" error.

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      addresses: [169.254.2.14/24]
```

I used this same netplan on Ubuntu MATE 18.04 (running on Pi 3) which worked fine.

I can, however, connect through WiFi, but the problem is that my school's WiFi will make it impossible for me to SSH it via wireless.

Comment: I'm trying to connect the Pi (running on Ubuntu) to my PC (running on Kubuntu)

Comment: Are you running an SSH server in at least one of the computers (the PC or the Pi)? You can install `openssh-server` in the computer you want as server and connect to it from the other one. You should also check that there is a network connection, and that you allow connecting (through the firewall).

Comment: More details about what you've tried would be great. I can see that you're on a 169.254.x.x address - which is typically used only by APIPA on Windows. Have you confirmed that the client you're trying to connect from is on the same subnet?

Comment: @user68186 just edited it.  I hope that's more detailed.  If not, let me know.

Comment: @sudodus it has `openssh-server`

Comment: @ddybing yes.  I have an ethernet dongle connected to my PC, which is set up to link-local.  It works fine on my Pi 3 running on Ubuntu MATE 18.04.

Comment: OK - so you've got an Ethernet cable directly connected to both with no switch inbetween? I suppose you are using a crossover cable?

Answer (score 1):

Must've been super groggy, because I didn't realize that the subnet I set for the Pi is 24, not 16.

After changing that and setting the renderer to `networkd`, it now works.

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      addresses: [169.254.2.14/16]
```

Though I set `NetworkManager`'s `ethernet.enabled` to true, so I thought that should've worked (`# snap set network-mananger ethernet.enable=true`, which I got from [here](https://docs.ubuntu.com/core/en/stacks/network/network-manager/docs/reference/configuration/ethernet_support)).

In addition, I had to run `# systemctl disable systemd-networkd-wait-online.service` & `# systemctl mask systemd-networkd-wait-online.service` in order for the Pi to boot faster (thanks to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/979493/558318)).  Leaving it enabled made the Pi stuck & waiting for connection (correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: systemd-networkd-wait-online.service blocks until you have a default Internet route.  According to your configuration above you don't have a default route.  So this service will wait and hit a timeout.  But what services do you have installed that depend on networkd-wait-online?  Services should only declare a dependency on this if they really care about getting out to the Internet; if you have such services installed, masking networkd-wait-online would not make your system more reliable.