# A start job is running for wait for network to be configured. Ubuntu server 20.04

Tags: boot, networking, server, 20.04, netplan

After reading [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/972215/a-start-job-is-running-for-wait-for-network-to-be-configured-ubuntu-server-17-1) post, I've followed [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1110474/616827) answer.
But , when I edit the `/etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml`, it was blank. So I create that file and add `optional: true`. After `sudo netplan apply`, It turns out to be an error `error in network definition unknown key 'optional'`.

Is the previous post answer still relevant for ubuntu 20.04? And he stated that:

> Don't mask or disable the systemd service.

So, what is the best solution for this in 20.04?

**edit:**
result of `ls /etc/netplan`

```
00-installer-config.yaml  01-netcfg.yaml
```

result of `cat /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml`

```
optional: true
```

result of `sudo lshw -C network` as @heynnema requested
[image: as @heynnema requested]
and result of `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`
[image]

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `ls /etc/netplan` and also: `cat /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml`

Comment: @chili555 there you go, I've edited it.

Comment: I order to help you, please edit your question and show me `sudo lshw -C network` and `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`. Did your Ubuntu Server install fail during the install?

Comment: @heynnema I've edited it. No. it didn't fail at all. In VBox, Using NAT is ok, but I want to use bridged adapter now to make it fixed IP.

Comment: You have two files: 00-installer-config.yaml  and 01-netcfg.yaml. We need to consolidate them into one non-conflicting file. May we see both?

Comment: @chili555 how??

Comment: I just got this problem too, on a fresh install of Ubuntu Server 20.04. The server has two ethernet ports, and the 'wait' is because only one of them is connected to a network, therefore the second one is waiting for DHCP to occur for up to the two minute time limit. The answer from @heynnema below sorted this for me, i.e. I just added the optional: true setting for the unused ethernet port, ran 'netplan generate' and 'netplan apply', rebooted, and the long wait is now gone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**In /etc/netplan:**

`sudo rm -i /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml` # remove unnecessary file

`sudo -H gedit /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml` # edit this file with these contents:

**For dhcp:**

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp0s3:
      dhcp4: true
      optional: true
```

**For static IP:** (bridged network)

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp0s3:
      addresses:
        - 192.168.x.xxx/24
      gateway4: 192.168.x.1
      nameservers:
        search: [mydomain, otherdomain]
        addresses: [8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4]
      optional: true
```

Create /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg

`sudo -H gedit /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg`

with the following content:

```
network: {config: disabled}
```

**Then:**

`sudo netplan generate`

`sudo netplan apply`

`reboot`

Comment: Gedit is supposed to be nano? Or vim?

Comment: @JastriaRahmat Yes, you can `sudo nano filename` if you like. Gedit is just a nice GUI editor that a lot of folks use already.

Comment: I will follow your answer asap. And see the result later. Thanks

Comment: @JastriaRahmat Status please...

Comment: @haven't tried it. I am outside the town currently.

Comment: @JastriaRahmat Status please...

Comment: it was working. thanks

Comment: Well, it didn't work for me... no idea why. Ubuntu 20.04. In the end I went back to the old-fashioned `/etc/network/interfaces` setup and _that_ worked. Mysterious...

Comment: @LaryxDecidua Please start a new question so I can help.