# How to disable unnecessary ethernet interfaces?

Tags: networking, ethernet

I have fresh latest Ubuntu server up and runnig on my Dell server. There are 3 ethernet interfaces on this machine but only one is in use. How to disable rest of them? I'm asking becauce on every boot i get ***A start job is running for wait for network to be configured*** message for about 3 minutes... Here some *ip address* output:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp8s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:10:18:39:b0:22 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:22:19:82:07:d1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp1s0
    inet 172.30.31.2/24 brd 172.30.31.255 scope global eno1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: eno2: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:22:19:82:07:d2 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp2s0
```

Comment: If you want to disable `eno2` then what does `systemctl | grep eno2` show? If there are services returned check each  of them (and for the 2nd interface too) and disable them

Comment: This is the output:

`' sys-devices-pci0000:00-0000:00:1c.5-0000:02:00.0-net-eno2.device
loaded active plugged   NetXtreme BCM5722 Gigabit Ethernet PCI Express (PowerEdge R300 Broadcom NetXtreme 5722)
  sys-subsystem-net-devices-eno2.device
loaded active plugged   NetXtreme BCM5722 Gigabit Ethernet PCI Express (PowerEdge R300 Broadcom NetXtreme 5722)'`

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/972215/a-start-job-is-running-for-wait-for-network-to-be-configured-ubuntu-server-17-1

Comment: From the link: "added "optional: true" on all others." Exactly correct!