# Failed to start Wait for Network to be Configured

Tags: boot, network-manager

I just upgraded my Ubuntu 22.04 LTS machine and now it gets stuck during boot with the message:

`[FAILED] Failed to start Wait for Network to be Configured`

on an otherwise black screen. I can still access the machine via ssh

`systemd-analyze blame` gives

```
2min 230ms systemd-networkd-wait-online.service
   17.473s networking.service
   12.039s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
   10.101s gpu-manager.service
    6.659s postgresql@14-main.service
    1.850s systemd-udev-settle.service
    1.688s plymouth-quit-wait.service
     762ms blueman-mechanism.service
     688ms dev-mapper-vglinux\x2droot.device
     604ms lvm2-pvscan@8:3.service
     343ms home-evehom-Megingjord.mount
     328ms boot-efi.mount
     267ms systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-0E9E\x2d46AA.service
     255ms udisks2.service
     206ms systemd-journal-flush.service
     190ms networkd-dispatcher.service
     187ms zfs-load-module.service
     172ms user@1000.service
     156ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
     150ms accounts-daemon.service
     126ms systemd-resolved.service
     107ms apparmor.service
     101ms NetworkManager.service
     101ms avahi-daemon.service
      99ms systemd-udevd.service
      94ms modprobe@chromeos_pstore.service
      92ms polkit.service
      89ms lvm2-monitor.service
      89ms systemd-journald.service
      87ms smbd.service
      76ms thermald.service
      74ms systemd-logind.service
      72ms wpa_supplicant.service
      70ms systemd-networkd.service
      62ms keyboard-setup.service
      62ms backup.mount
      60ms ModemManager.service
      59ms preload.service
      53ms grub-common.service
      52ms alsa-restore.service
      39ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
      38ms modprobe@drm.service
      37ms casper-md5check.service
      35ms home.mount
      35ms systemd-sysctl.service
      34ms nmbd.service
      34ms ssh.service
      32ms packagekit.service
      31ms lm-sensors.service
      31ms cups.service
      31ms systemd-modules-load.service
      30ms e2scrub_reap.service
      27ms rsyslog.service
      27ms hddtemp.service
      25ms run-rpc_pipefs.mount
      25ms resolvconf-pull-resolved.service
      24ms lightdm.service
      22ms ntp.service
      22ms dev-hugepages.mount
      22ms dev-mapper-vglinux\x2dswap_1.swap
      22ms dev-mqueue.mount
      21ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
      20ms sys-kernel-tracing.mount
      20ms zfs-volume-wait.service
      18ms plymouth-start.service
      17ms kmod-static-nodes.service
      16ms grub-initrd-fallback.service
      14ms modprobe@configfs.service
      13ms ubiquity.service
      13ms zfs-mount.service
      13ms modprobe@fuse.service
      12ms plymouth-read-write.service
      12ms systemd-sysusers.service
      10ms zfs-share.service
      10ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
       9ms systemd-random-seed.service
       9ms systemd-remount-fs.service
       8ms dns-clean.service
       8ms user-runtime-dir@1000.service
       8ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
       7ms rpc-statd-notify.service
       7ms rpcbind.service
       6ms modprobe@efi_pstore.service
       6ms modprobe@pstore_blk.service
       6ms systemd-update-utmp.service
       6ms modprobe@pstore_zone.service
       6ms openvpn.service
       6ms console-setup.service
       5ms modprobe@ramoops.service
       5ms ifupdown-pre.service
       5ms sys-kernel-config.mount
       5ms systemd-user-sessions.service
       4ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
       4ms finalrd.service
       3ms rtkit-daemon.service
       2ms setvtrgb.service
       1ms postgresql.service
      28us blk-availability.service
```

I found this thread [A start job is running for wait for network to be configured. Ubuntu server 17.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/972215/a-start-job-is-running-for-wait-for-network-to-be-configured-ubuntu-server-17-1?noredirect=1&lq=1) and added `optional: true` to `/etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml` but to no avail, after applying this and rebooting the machine still gets stuck at `[FAILED] Failed to start Wait for Network to be Configured`.

Any pointers to avoid a complete OS reinstall would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance/Evert

```
cat /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml 

network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp0s3:
      dhcp4: yes
      optional: true

ls /etc/netplan/
01-netcfg.yaml
```

I managed to fix the problem, for some reason the Nvidia drivers had become uninstalled. I installed them command line and can now access the GUI again. Everything seems to work as normal.

Thanks for your consideration/Evert

Comment: If this is an ordinary desktop installation, not a server, you don't need 01-netcfg.yaml, you need 01-network-manager-all.yaml. Is there a conflict here? Please edit your question to show: `cat /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml` and also: `ls /etc/netplan` Please redact any sensitive details with xxxx. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.