# MySQL not running

Tags: server, 20.04, mysql, nginx

I recently upgraded my Ubuntu server to the latest version, and when I tried to access my website I got this error:

```
Flarum encountered a boot error (Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException)
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory
thrown in /var/www/seekadventure.net/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php on line 31
```

I think it is an issue with MySQL, so I tried to get the status of MySQL with `service mysql status` and I got this in return:

```
mysql.service
     Loaded: masked (Reason: Unit mysql.service is masked.)
     Active: inactive (dead)
```

After that I tried to start MySQL with `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start` but when I ran `service mysql status` again I got the same as before...

I then tried to see if maybe it was running but not showing with the status command. So I tried `netstat -tlnp` but I only saw these processes running:

[image]

Comment: Maybe helpful: [What is a masked service?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1017311/what-is-a-masked-service)

Comment: @steeldriver i Unmasked it but I and I can see it running but it doesnt show up when I run netstat -tlnp

I want to check what port its on.