# How do i stop pulseaudio?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

In this version of ubuntu, pulseaudio is a service started for the user. The different commands tried

```
> pulseaudio -k
> systemctl --user stop pulseaudio
```

```
> changing pulse.conf to include autospawn=no
> systemctl daemon-reload
> systemctl --user stop pulseaudio
```

```
> pkill -9 pulseaudio
```

It respawns all the time because systemd restarts it. Should i kill the systemd --user instance or is there something else that is tweakable?

Answer (score 4):

You need to stop the systemd user socket.

systemctl --user stop pulseaudio.socket

systemctl --user stop pulseaudio.service

You can also use the disable, enable, reload, and restart commands as well.
That should stop pulseaudio from respawning until you start it back up.
Hope that helps

Answer (score 2):

Disabling the service doesn't work. You have to also mask it:

```
systemctl --user stop pulseaudio.socket
systemctl --user stop pulseaudio.service
systemctl --user disable pulseaudio.socket
systemctl --user disable pulseaudio.service
systemctl --user mask pulseaudio.socket
systemctl --user mask pulseaudio.service
```

Comment: If this is not working, try closing QjackCtl

Answer (score 0):

You need to find out what else depends on pulseaudio and kill/stop those before stopping `pulseaudio`.

```
systemctl --user --reverse list-dependencies pulseaudio
```

See also: https://askubuntu.com/a/816378/145907