# Relationship of rsyslog and journald on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, server, logging, rsyslog, systemd-journald

I am running what is a vanilla Ubuntu 16.04 server, and I'm trying to wrap my head around how logging is set up by default. I can see that both `journald` and `rsyslog` are installed and running, but it's not at all clear to me how log messages are being processed.

Most messages seem to show up both in `/var/log/syslog` and via `journalctl`, but I can't see any explicit configuration for forwarding between the two in either `/etc/systemd/journald.conf` (which is basically all commented out by default), `/etc/rsyslog.conf` or `/etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf`.
I tried to look for official documentation, or even a blog post explaining how hese two are set up in Ubuntu, but haven't managed to find anything.

<del>To further add to my confusion, I have executed `logger -p local1.info Test` on the host, and found that nothing was written to `/var/log/syslog`, while the message did show up under `journalctl`.</del>

My questions are:

1. How exactly do journald and rsyslog work together on Ubuntu 16.04 (by default)?
2. <del>How come messages sent from `logger` seemingly end up in the journal, but not in syslog?</del>

Update: Turns out `logger` not working as expected was a mistake on my end, so it's not relevant to the main question.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

By default `rsyslog` is using "imuxsock" module, the module provides:

> the ability to accept syslog messages via local Unix sockets. Most importantly, this is the mechanism by which the syslog(3) call delivers syslog messages to rsyslogd [[1]](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/master/configuration/modules/imuxsock.html).

It is possible for `rsyslog` to  import structured log messages from systemd-journal using a module named "imjournal" [[2]](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/master/configuration/modules/imjournal.html).

It can be load like:

```
module(load="imjournal")
```

in:

```
/etc/rsyslog.conf
```

In the other hand "systemd-journald" captures all data itself:

```
man systemd-journald
```

> systemd-journald is a system service that collects and stores logging data. It creates and maintains structured, indexed journals based on logging information that is received from a variety of sources:
>
> ```
>    ·   Kernel log messages, via kmsg
>    ·   Simple system log messages, via the libc syslog(3) call
>    ·   Structured system log messages via the native Journal API, 
>        see sd_journal_print(4)
>    ·   Standard output and standard error of system services
>    ·   Audit records, via the audit subsystem
> ```

You can disable `rsyslogd` while you still have access to system logs using `journalctl`.

```
$ sudo systemctl mask rsyslogd
$ sudo systemctl stop syslog.socket
$ sudo systemctl stop rsyslog.service
$ systemctl is-active rsyslog.service 
inactive
$ logger -p mail.info Helllooo
$ journalctl
```

For example, centos is using "imuxsock" module to capture all "systemd-journald" data via `rsyslog` while opensuse does not have "syslog" at all.

---

To find out why your message didn't end up to `/var/log/syslog`, you should check this file:

```
less /etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf
```

look for `*.info`, see where they will be stored, it might be an other file like `messages`.

*For me it show up in both `journalctl` and `syslog`.*

Comment: `logger -p .info hello` is not valid. You have not given any facility name.

Comment: Updated the answer ....

Comment: As I noted in my edit, `logger` not working was my fault, so that's fixed now (thanks for the tips anyway). As for logs showing up in two places, your note on `imuxsock` seems to be the key: it seems both rsyslog and journald are listening for local syslog messages, hence why those entries go into two separate logs.

Comment: I followed the above on ubuntu and now I'm not getting any logs from logger, hmm:

    root@T:~# logger -p mail.info Helllooo
    root@T:~# journalctl
    No journal files were found.
    -- No entries -- 

any ideas?

Comment: Great answer. What I'm missing,though, is a note about how journald knows to open a syslog socket (or if it does not, how it gets at syslog messages otherwise) when rsyslog is disabled? Or is some manual configuration of journald needed?

Comment: The answer explains how both can work, but not what actually happens.

Comment: The missing bit of magic in 16.04 is that `imuxsock` is hard-coded to look at `/run/systemd/journal/syslog` ( `SYSTEMD_PATH_LOG` ) and `/lib/systemd/system/syslog.socket` has `ListenDatagram=/run/systemd/journal/syslog` and that triggers `/etc/systemd/system/syslog.service -> /lib/systemd/system/rsyslog.service` *and* `debian/patches/Re-enable-journal-forwarding-to-syslog.patch` makes `ForwardToSyslog` the default, with only the barest documentation update.

Answer (score 9):

Systemd is an init system used to start the services when the system boots up.
Journald is responsible for making logs for services that are started by systemd. By integrating journald with systemd, even the earliest
boot process messages are available to journald.

Rsyslog is a daemon specially made for log processing, nothing to do with journald. It can take logs in by many ways and output them in many ways. It is not enabled by default that it takes log messages from journald also. For that, you have to write in /etc/rsyslog.conf file,

```
$ModLoad imjournal # im -> input module
OR
load(type="imjournal")
```

Now, it will accept logs fromm journald also. But I suggest you should not change your /etc/rsyslog.conf file.

At the end of /etc/rsyslog.conf file, there is a line written,

```
$IncludeConfig /etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf
```

It means that all the files having .conf at there end in the /etc/rsyslog.d/ folder should be included during rsyslog loading. So, all your custom configs should go in these files

I would suggest you to make a file /etc/rsyslog.d/journald.conf and paste the below snippet in that.

Below is the snippet from the rsyslog official page of imjournal

```
module(load="imjournal" PersistStateInterval="100"
   StateFile="/path/to/file") #load imjournal module
module(load="mmjsonparse") #load mmjsonparse module for structured logs

template(name="CEETemplate" type="string" string="%TIMESTAMP% %HOSTNAME% %syslogtag% @cee: %$!all-json%\n" ) #template for messages

action(type="mmjsonparse")
action(type="omfile" file="/var/log/ceelog" template="CEETemplate")
```

Line 1 - it loads the imjournal module for accepting the logs from journald

2 - The mmjsonparse module is loaded used in parsing of the logs

3 - They are structured into the described format in the template

4 - It parses those logs using the mmjsonparse module.

5 - It sends those logs to a file namely /var/log/ceelog according to the structure provided in the given template, using the omfile(output module file - outputs to file) module.

Make changes in the config according to your need.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but I think the answer by @Ravexina is closer to helping me understand what's going on with rsyslog and journald, *by default* (without extra configuration).