# Where are the logs from underneath the splashscreen?

Tags: log, plymouth

Is there a logfile of the messages that are printed onscreen underneath the splash screen in 16.04?  If so, where are they, or what is the name of the file?

Answer (score 2):

Use `dmesg` to print kernel buffer ring logs, or use `journalctl -b` to get messages from last boot, you can take a look at `/var/log/syslog` too.

Comment: Does `journalctl` put info into `/var/log/syslog`? I have been wondering if that was the case.

Comment: @George read [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/925440/relationship-of-rsyslog-and-journald-on-ubuntu-16-04/925446#925446)